# Stable sort dynamically created array which contains duplicates (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I've been working on this for a couple of days, looked through all the other threads but can't seem to find a solution to my problem.

I start off with an object array, each specifying a 'start' and 'end' number. I loop through the difference between these, creating a new object from each number in between, storing the 'name' data in each new object created.

After which, I would like to sort the data based off the number, but maintaining the placement order of the original array.

```js
const data = [{
  'start': 10,
  'finish': 14,
  'name': 'one'
}, {
  'start': 14,
  'finish': 19,
  'name': 'two'
}, {
  'start': 12,
  'finish': 16,
  'name': 'three'
}]

let newData = [];

for (let d of data) {
  const start = d.start;
  const finish = d.finish;
  
  for (let i = start; i <= finish; i++) {
    newData.push({
      'number': i,
      'name': d.name
    })
  }
}

const sortData = (data) => newData.sort((a, b) => a.number - b.number)

const result = sortData(data)

// Test order for number 14

for(let r of result){
  if(r['number'] == 14){
    console.log(r.name)
  }
}

// Show all data

console.log(result)
```

Sorry for the long snippet, but it's difficult for me to display the problem.

At the moment, when looking for the items with the number '14' after the sort, the names displayed are 'two, three, one'. I would like to instead maintain the original order of the 'data' array, so it should display as 'one, two, three'.

I'm not sure how sort() is deciding what goes where, because if I change the second object's finish number to 17 inside the original data array it will display the items for number '14' in the correct order.

Just to repeat - I would like to sort the newData array by the number but placed in the order of the original 'data' array.

I hope everything is clear! Please let me know if I can improve the question some how.

Here is a plunkr with the code - http://plnkr.co/edit/tM0h4C93CAnyy1g0T3jp?p=preview.

Comment: Use of `for of` is for objects because order isn't guaranteed so in turn it's use for arrays is discouraged or I might be confusing `for in` and `for of`...Just checked `for of` is ok for arrays, it's `for in` you gotta be careful about. BTW, perhaps the order isn't by number value but instead alphabetical order being that two,three, one looks like reverse alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a stable sort, you need another propery, like the index of the array.

With a new property,

```js
const data = [{ start: 10, finish: 14, name: 'one' }, { start: 14, finish: 19, name: 'two' }, { start: 12, finish: 16, name: 'three' }]
let newData = [];

data.forEach((d, pos) => {
  const start = d.start;
  const finish = d.finish;
  
  for (let i = start; i <= finish; i++) {
    newData.push({ number: i, name: d.name, pos })
  }
});

const sortData = (data) => newData.sort((a, b) => a.number - b.number || a.pos - b.pos)
const result = sortData(data)

// Test order for number 14
for(let r of result){
  if(r['number'] == 14){
    console.log(r.name)
  }
}
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

or sort by name with an object.

```js
const data = [{ start: 10, finish: 14, name: 'one' }, { start: 14, finish: 19, name: 'two' }, { start: 12, finish: 16, name: 'three' }]
let newData = [];
let order = Object.create(null);

data.forEach((d, pos) => {
  const start = d.start;
  const finish = d.finish;
  order[d.name] = pos;
  
  for (let i = start; i <= finish; i++) {
    newData.push({ number: i, name: d.name })
  }
});

const sortData = (data) => newData.sort((a, b) => a.number - b.number || order[a.name] - order[b.name])
const result = sortData(data)

// Test order for number 14
for(let r of result){
  if(r['number'] == 14){
    console.log(r.name)
  }
}
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Ah okay! - I think adding a new property will work better in my case. Thanks for the answer!